# How do I sum two Poisson processes?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

> If we have a Poisson Process $Y$ with intensity $\lambda$ and a Poisson Process $X$ with intensity $\mu$, where $X$ and $Y$ are two independent Poisson processes. How can I find the process $Z=Y+X$?

I know it should involve convolutions in some way but I dont know how to construct it!

Comment: Do you require that X and Y are independant?

Comment: yes, X and Y are independent processes

Comment: You should probably add that to your question then.

Answer (score 5):

#### Hint: $$P(Z=z)=P(X+Y=z)=\sum_{x=0}^z f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)$$

So, we have 
$$
f_Z(z)=\sum_{x=0}^z e^{-\mu} \dfrac{\mu^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda} \cdot\dfrac{\lambda^{z-x}}{(z-x)!} \\ =e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\sum_{x=0}^z \dfrac{\mu^x}{x!} \cdot\dfrac{\lambda^{z-x}}{(z-x)!}\\=e^{-(\lambda+\mu)}\cdot \dfrac{(\lambda+\mu)^z}{z!}[\text{Use of binomial formula}]
$$