# Properties of a counting process $\{ N(t) : t \geq 0 \}$

Tags: probability

I am learning about counting processes now. If we have $N(t) = N_1 (t) + N_2 (t)$, where $ \{ N_1 (t) : t \geq 0 \}$ and $\{ N_2 (t) : t \geq 0 \}$ are two independent counting processes, I want to check certain properties. Is $\{ N(t) : t \geq 0 \}$ a counting process? And are the interval times of $N(t)$ identically distributed and are these independent? Intuitively I would say yes on these questions, but how can I mathematically argue this is true or not?

Since $N_1$ is a counting process, the interval times of $N_1$ are independent and identically distributed. Same for $N_2$. Is it correct to say that the interval times of their sum are identically distributed too? And same argument for independence.

It doesn't help the only thing my book says about a counting process $N(t)$ is that it counts the number of events during time $t$.

Comment: here you find some useful insights http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385417/how-do-i-sum-two-poisson-processes

Comment: That is limited to the case of poisson processes. I am looking for a general case.